# Variable "entry" does not exist

Tags: templating, variable

This is very basic as I am new to Craft CMS, but I created a Plain Text field in the Homepage section labeled "Tagline". When I enter the Twig code `{{ entry.tagline }}` into the index.html template, I get the error that the variable "entry" does not exist.

My index.html is at the root of the public folder.

Comment: Hi Nick and welcome to the Craft CMS Stack Exchange site! Can you update your question to add details like the URL, where your template file lives, and what the template itself looks like? It sounds like something isn't set up quite right. You can always take a look at the [Happy Lager demo site](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/HappyLager) to see an install or compare to what you've got.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the index.html should be within your templates folder. Is it? 
And make sure that you Homepage section is actually pointing to that template. Look at your sections part within Craft CMS.